# How do I make this menu using only HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html

I am relatively new to HTML/CSS. I'd appreciate it if everything could be explained step by step.

I would like to imitate (for training purposes) [this menu (including a custom logo image)](http://justinmezzell.com/). I do no have any idea on how to approach it or how to put it on every page of the site. If possible could be done using only HTML5 and CSS?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you make a container for the links. In the container you need elements which have "hrefs" to the destination. The main thing used for this is a list(ul).
Then you make the elements inside this ul have the property `display:inline-block` which makes them stack horizontally. These so called list items will have bullet points.

To remove those, you have to add `list-style-type: none'`.

You can see this here: https://jsfiddle.net/0ffzj93f/5/

For putting it on every page, just copy paste and change the "current" class to the appropriate link.

Answer (score 0):

make a list.`<ul><li></ul>`.put an image inside the first li `<li><img></img></li>`.There rest is just some css formating use display inline in css and adjust colors and img size :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheoBearman/tc3h5toj/) using the code from the link you provided. You'll have to use the HTML I've put on the fiddle and isolate the `topNav`, `main-nav` and `li` elements from the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
header:after{
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
h1{
  float: left;
}
ul{
  float: right;
}
ul > li{
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1><img width="200" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/51ba2198e4b089e26e4a4631/t/51d47005e4b0386d63b4d738/1422327510900/?format=1000w" alt="logo"></h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Home<li>
    <li>Work<li>
    <li>About<li>
    <li>Contact<li>
    <li>Home<li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily use the http://foundation.zurb.com/. I always use it.It is responsive with toggle bar and you have the option to make it sticky (always on top no matter what). There are a lot more features that you can use. Here is an example:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

If you need more information let me know